# Crystal Reports in PHP Application using XML

Tags: php, xml, com, crystal-reports

I have a requirement as below:

- I have a PHP Web Application with ability to connect to any DB with PDO.
- I have a report generating script that will give me the report data in XML
- Using the XSD from XML as Data Source, i have to define a Crystal report RPT file.
- I have to call this RPT in runtime dynamically, during which the PHP Script will generate the XML document from DB and using this XML as Input to my RPT, the rendered report should be sent to the users browser.

I have googled to address this using PHP-COM but could not find what i exactly want..

Answer (score 0):

- Expose the XML/XSD documents via a RESTful web service; the web service will be responsible for querying the database and creating the XML file.  The XSD should be a one-time effort.
- Manually create a RPT that references the web service's URL.
- Publish your report as a web service: [How Do I Work with Crystal Reports as Web Services?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225456%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- Interact with CRWS using your PHP application.